# Is sheer beauty a proper way to describe a movie

Tags: word-usage, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I asked my friend to describe me a movie and he wrote, "**it is more than one time watchable for it's sheer beauty**".

I do not understand this sentence and i do not think it is used correctly. Also the usage of 'sheer beauty' seems wrong to me.

English is not my first language so I need to get someone to tell me if this sentence is correct or wrong.

Comment: Have you tried a Google search? Calvin Klein seems to find the expression quite acceptable.

Comment: "More than one time watchable" is questionable, but "sheer beauty" is appropriately used (if indeed the movie is that good).

Comment: Any dictionary will define adjectival [**sheer**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sheer?s=t) *- unqualified, utter:* Note that the *beauty of a thing* is ***its** beauty*, and as @Hot Licks suggests, "More than one time watchable" is [**highly**] questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use *sheer beauty* in this way.

Sheer beauty, in this sense, means that the film is very beautiful and that its beauty can be considered on its own.

So, your friend is saying that the film is so very beautiful that, irrespective of its other virtues or faults, it incites repeat viewings.

However, there are some errors in your sentence: *it is more than one time watchable* is incorrect grammar, also *it's* means *it is* - you mean *its*.

> ***It can be watched more than once for its sheer beauty.***

Or, even better:

> ***Its sheer beauty inspires repeat viewings.***

Comment: I can see now what the problem was in the sentence.

Comment: How does "sheer" mean beauty on its own?  As @FumbleFingers pointed out, it means "unqualified, utter".

Comment: @KristinaLopez - Sheer does have this meaning, as any dictionary will confirm. Quoted from thefreedictionary.com: "Considered or operating apart from anything else: *got the job through sheer persistence.*"

Comment: Oh, I misread it that you were saying "sheer" means beauty.  What you were actually saying was that "sheer beauty" means the beauty stands on its own. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez - Ah fair enough :) Perhaps an edit is in order for the sake of clarity...

Comment: Or maybe I just need more coffee! :-)